# How to parse values like \x00, \x95x95?

Tags: python

I have String which is like:
`\x00\x00\x01\x90\x27` and on.

How can I parse this value to a simple long value?

Like, what is the long value of `\x00`?  `0` or `00`?

Comment: What do you mean by long value? If you mean the decimal representation, 0 and 00 are the same number.

Comment: What's the difference between 0 and 00?

Comment: Python version 2 or 3?

Comment: Is `\x00` the real content of the string or do we talk about the string representation?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you thing your data is character...

So using python 3

```
 a=b'\x00\x00\x01\x90'
 b=b.decode('utf-8')
```

If your binary data has some 'nasty' i.e. bad characters this will fail - but adding an option like errors='ignore' or errors='replace' will assist you unhanding those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear so I am making some assumptions here. If you need fixed length conversions then you can use standard [structs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.

For example:

```
In [11]: unpack('>i', '\x00\x01\x90\x27')
Out[11]: (102439,)
```

if you need variable length string then something like this will work (for unsigned and watch for endianness):

```
s = '\x00\x00\x01\x90\x27'
i = 0
for c in s:
    i <<= 8
    i |= ord(c)

print i
```